# Add Function Extensions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'd like to know to add in something like function extensions, example:
console.* [ console.log(); console.warn(); console.info(); etc... ]

How does one accomplish this in very simeple JavaScript?

I'd like to go ~ echo.true() and echo.false() with an area to work with very easily..!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `window.echo = { ... }` PS: it's not obvious why you call it "extensions".

Comment: Look for documentation around javascript Class.Method().
You want to define a "echo" class having true() and false() methods.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is an inline object declaration :

```js
var echo = {
 true : function () { alert("true"); },
 false : function () { alert("false"); }
};
echo.true();
```